# Drupal 6 Feeds: admin/build/feeds empty importers

Tags: php, drupal, import, feed

I have a Drupal production site setup on ec2 dedicated server.

Following are the main settings:

Drupal: 6.16
MySQL:  5.1.57
PHP:    5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
Memory Limit:   256M
Webserver: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
jQuery UI: 1.8
jQuery Update: 1.3.2

ctools: 6.x-1.9

Feeds: 6.x-1.0-beta12
Feeds Admin UI: 6.x-1.0-beta12
Feeds Fast News: 6.x-1.0-beta12
Feeds Import: 6.x-1.0-beta12
Feeds News: 6.x-1.0-beta12

The problem is that if I go to admin/build/feeds, the importers list is empty. When I flush the cache (admin_menu/flush-cache), the list reappears, but after navigating different site pages, when I revisit the admin/build/feeds, the importers list is empty again.

The same happens with the Import tab at the feed node pages (I am using feed as the source content type).

I have tried the following:

- Explicitly clear the cache using Drupal's cache functions
- Modify the feeds_importer_load_all function to set the required ctools static variables.
- Increased PHP memory limit to 512MB
- Completely disable the cache.
- Explicitly disable the cache with $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE; in hook_init
- And a few other patches as well

$cache = &ctools_static(**FUNCTION**);
$cached_database = &ctools_static('ctools_export_load_object_all');

in function ctools_export_load_object are always empty and blank schema is returned.

None of above is solving the problem.

Does any one has experienced any similar scenario or knows what can be wrong with it? Appreciate the assistance in the matter.

Comment: You might get a better response here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the query as drupal.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: Link: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44108/drupal-6-feeds-admin-build-feeds-empty-importers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

The problem was with drupal_get_schema function. I applied drupal 6 patch http://drupal.org/files/issues/schema_cache_402896_D6.patch from thread http://drupal.org/node/402896 and it worked.

The apparent problem seems to be with the fact that drupal_get_schema was loading complete schema cache; which was not working on a specific environment with relatively limited resources, even though a specific table was specified.

Thanks.